# ActiveDirectory change all UPN

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have to change all UPN in my Active Directory. Some UPN are completely empty an some are filled.

Now I want to fill them all with their `sAMAccountName`.

My script looks like this:

```
# Import AD Module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory            

# Import CSV into variable $userscsv            
#$userscsv = import-csv C:\temp\rename\usernames.csv            
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\temp\rename\usernames.csv           
# Loop through CSV and update users if the exist in CVS file
foreach ($user in $users) {
    #Search in specified OU and Update existing attributes
    Get-ADUser -Filter "sAMAccountName -eq '$($user.samaccountname)'"
    Set-ADUser -userPrincipalName $($users.samaccountname)           
}
```

I get an errorcode:

```
Get-ADUser : Der Suchfilter wurde nicht erkannt
Bei C:\TEMP\RENAME\User-Rename.ps1:13 Zeichen:12
+  Get-ADUser <<<<  -Filter "sAMAccountName -eq '$($user.samaccountname)'"     
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Der Suchfilter wurde nicht erkannt,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: how your csv file looks? add some lines of it...

Comment: Name,Benutzeranmeldename,E Mail-Adresse,Typ,Beschreibung,Anmeldename für Prä-Windows 2000
Amanu2 ext. Schreibdienst,amanu2@domain.local, ,Benutzer,,amanu2
Ambulanz Leitung, , ,Benutzer,Ambulanz Leitung,Ambulanz Leitung

Comment: EEG, ,eeg@domain.de,Benutzer,EEG,eeg

Comment: where is your 'samaccountname' column?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend setting the UPN to the SamAccountName. That's not how it's [supposed to be](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you must do it anyway, you can't use subexpressions in a filter. Assign the value to a variable and use that in the filter expression. You also need to pipe the user object into `Set-ADUser` to give the cmdlet something to work with:

```
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $acct = $user.SamAccountName
    Get-ADUser -Filter "sAMAccountName -eq '$acct'" |
        Set-ADUser -userPrincipalName $acct
}
```

Comment: Same error
Get-ADUser : Der Suchfilter wurde nicht erkannt
Bei C:\TEMP\RENAME\User-Rename.ps1:13 Zeichen:15
+     Get-ADUser <<<<  -Filter "sAMAccountName -eq '$acct'" |
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Der Suchfilter wurde nicht erkannt,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUse

Comment: @user2942606 `$acct` is null or empty. Remove blank lines from your CSV.

Comment: @user2942606 Addendum: make sure your CSV actually contains a column with the title `SamAccountName`.